# Creat point count trigger in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, trigger

I wish to create a trigger in PostgreSQL for counting points in a polygon.

The tweak is that the count should automatically get updated whenever the polygon is edited.

Can anyone please help me on the same?